# Magento 2 : use_config_min_sale_qty on website states 10

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, quantity

When I add a new product or a product option to a configurable product it sets the `min_sale_qty` to 10 which states a message like: The fewest you may purchase is 10.

I want to set this for all products to 1 because this is the min order qty for the cart. Where in the database or magento can I set a default setting for all products and override old settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be easily done in admin panel.
Go to `Admin -> Stores -> Configuration->Catalog->Inventory->Minimum qty allowed in Shopping Cart` for setting it to all the products for a customer group.

If you want to set it for individual products , go to product edit , click advanced inventory and set  `Minimum qty allowed in Shopping Cart` to your required value .